# HTML5 Video using video.js won't play until fully downloaded

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-9, autoplay, loaded

I have a strange issue with a html5 video. It's working correctly in all browsers except in Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer 9 is always waiting for the video to be fully downloaded until playback starts. If I open the Video in Firefox, Chrome or even Opera everything is working fine.

The code snippet looks as following

```
<video id="video-js-10734" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="480" controls="controls" autoplay="enabled" data-setup="{}" poster="1"><source src="http://www.lorch.biz/fileadmin/DAM_Lorch/Bilddaten/800-Doku/web/Videos/I-Torch_Movie_Full_HD_libtheora.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> <source src="http://www.lorch.biz/fileadmin/DAM_Lorch/Bilddaten/800-Doku/web/Videos/I-Torch_Movie_Full_HD_x264.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> </video>
```

Did I forget about some keyword configuration or is this a "feature" in Internet &*°ç&*ç! Explorer?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like IE doesn't use the same file as other browsers.
I don't remember if IE support OGV files but if not IE should use the mp4 file you provide. It seems then your mp4 hasn't a delay set for autostart.

I have used sometimes a program called MP4box to mux or demux the file so it can start without loading everything.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting approach! I will try to get in contact with the media creator. THX a lot!

Comment: Ok, the demux approach worked for me. It appears that MP4Box actually resets the Indexes for MP4 during the new mux afterwards. The file then can be streamed by IE9 without any problem.

Comment: Heh, even stackoverflow relies on stats :-D

Answer (score 0):

May be IE doesn't support progressive download for type="video/ogg". Only for H264 and WebM. However you specidy the mp4 file. Try use type="video/ogg" and .ogg file as last option and type="video/mp4" and .mp4 file as first one.

Comment: Tried it but it didn't get any better. Looks like the sorting of <source> - tags does not make any difference.